# Is it possible to override LoginView in function based views, not as a class?

Tags: python, django

I understand that in order to override from `django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView` one has to use a subclass `Class(LoginView)` in views.py.

However, in my views.py I only have views declared with `def my_view(request)`

In old versions of Django I could just do

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout
def login_user(request):
    result = login(request=request, template_name='Market/pages/login.html')
    return result
```

What's the modern Django equivalent of this? The documentation has this example, that forces me rewrite the whole username/password logic into my view:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def my_view(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        # Redirect to a success page.
        ...
    else:
        # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
        ...
```

How can I use a view function (not class!) and still have the automatic managing of the submitted request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the point. The reason behind the move to class-based views is that they are *more* configurable than function-based ones.

In this case, you don't even need to define your own view to get the result you want; you can just do it in the URL:

```
path('login/', views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='Market/pages/login.html'), name='login')
```

Comment: So do you recommend mixing class-based views and function-based one in the same views.py? Or am I doing something bad if I do that?

Comment: yes you can mix it and nothing bad would hapen